# What is a good Framework to develop a C# single application that run on both MacOS and Windows? I need to manage Gui and BItmaps

Tags: windows, c#, gui, macos

I have some years experience with .net core and WinForm. Now I need to develop a graphics application in Visual Studio for Windows that run on both OS. Can you help me to understand and make a good choice? Maybe Unity the way? QT?
Here an [image: Alpha Stage Tile Generator]image that show something similar developed by me with WinForm and c#.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Winforms itself runs on both OSs (though Mono for Mac). If you're careful on what features do you use you can get it working right away without too much adjustments.

Comment: I read that mono don't work with .Net Core but only .Net framework.

Comment: Yes, .NET Core GUI implementations are Windows-only. Just use the real .NET Framework and Winforms, plus Mono on Mac and you can run your programs pretty much unmodified on both systems.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll find information. Just to know. Do i need a Mac to produce it or I can work directly under Windows?

Comment: You can compile it on Windows directly and run the built .exe unmodified on Mac though Mono.